# Active Search Bar for images

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an an ID to my images so I can search through a large list of them. 
I have CSS so that my images are in line 
My HTML

```html
<html>
 <title>WhitePaper Repository</title>
 <head>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <h1 align=center>Header</h1>
  <h2 align=center>Sub-Header</h2>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
  <input type="text" id="myinput" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="images">
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/btc.png" alt="Bitcoin"></a>
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/ethereum.png" alt="Ethereum"></a>
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/ripple.png" alt="Ripple"></a>
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/Bitcoin_Cash.png" alt="Bitcoin Cash"></a>
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/ada.png" alt="Cardano"></a>
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/nem.png" alt="NEM"></a>
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/Litecoin.png" alt="LiteCoin"></a>
   <a href="https://example.com"><img src="img/stellar.png" alt="Stellar Lumens"></a>
   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
 
    var input, filter, div, a, img, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myinput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("images");
    a = ul.getElementsByTagName('a');


    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I would like to be able to add ids or something to each of the images so when people search using the search bar only the examples of the ones that contain the letters remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myinput" name="search" placeholder="search..." style="width:200px; height: 40px; border-radius: 4px; font-size: 18px;"><br>
<div id="images">
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://vu.hn/images/BitcoinCashLogo.png" alt="Bitcoin" width=130></a>
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://www.ethereum.org/images/logos/ETHEREUM-LOGO_PORTRAIT_Black_small.png" alt="Ethereum" width=130></a>
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ripple-Logo.png" alt="Ripple" width=130></a>
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://i.redd.it/tsmzy49d4adz.jpg" alt="Bitcoin Cash" width=130></a>
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://themerkle.com/wp-content/uploads/cardano.jpg" alt="Cardano" width=130></a>
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DJkf7M4VYAAgt8V.png" alt="NEM" width=130></a>
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://bitkee.com/icons/litecoin-logo.png" alt="LiteCoin" width=130></a>
            <a href="https://example.com"><img src="http://bittrust.s3.amazonaws.com/1486429998.png" alt="Stellar Lumens" width=130></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$("#myinput").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (val === "")
        $('img').show();
    else {
        $('img').hide();
        $("img[alt*=" + val + "]").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

[image]

The GIF makes it looks slow but this is fast in reality. 
You can also make the search case insensitive.

** EDIT **

As per additional requests:

**Making it case insensitive, and spaces in the attribute searchable:**

Adding the *case insensitivity flag* 'i' inside the regex part of the selector makes it case insensitive:

```
$("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show();
```

And escaping spaces:

```
val = val.split(" ").join("\\ ");
```

in attribute selector makes spaced attributes searchable by jquery. This is to account for Jquery's API-like syntax for selectors, which allows us to target spaced attributes. The new code is:

```
$("#myinput").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (val === "")
        $('img').show();
    else {
        $('img').hide();
        val = val.split(" ").join("\\ ");
        $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show();
    }
});
```

**Aligning images with css and clickable overlay:**

This can be done using the following approach:

```
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <a href="https://example.com"><img src="images/bit_logo.png" alt="Bitcoin" width=130><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Bitcoin</div></div></a>   
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <a href="https://example.com"><img src="images/ethereum_logo.png" alt="Ethereum" width=130><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ethereum</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <a href="https://example.com"><img src="images/ripple_logo.png" alt="Ripple" width=130><div class="overlay"><div class="text">Ripple</div></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**...along with appropriate styling:**

```
.imgContainer{
    float:left;
}
img {
width: 120px !important; 
}
body {
background: white !important; 
}
.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.imgContainer:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The following shows both **bitcoin** and **bitcoin cash** searchable, along with aligned images with clickable overlays:

[image]

Comment: Perfect wow this is great
How would I go about making it case insensitive?
Additionally I have a CSS hover code to change the background color when the mouse is over an image.
How would I also have a text overlay with the alt name of the image when the mouse is over it

Comment: You can add a case insensitivity flag 'i' inside the regex part of the selector. So you would change $("img[alt*=" + val + "]").show(); to this $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show(); (note the addition of the "i").

Comment: For text overlays I would use the title attribute instead of alt. If you really want to use alt text see here https://codepen.io/Sarah_C/pen/OymZRO

Comment: Thanks man, if you are still willing to assist me that would be great, if not its understandable.
I uploaded what I currently have here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpWdmB
As I believe my current CSS messes with the outline as every image is on a new line.
Also searches with a space like Bitcoin Cash dont appear, and the text overlays still appear after a search even if that image no longer appears

Comment: I adjusted the css and html to align images. I also adjusted the query attribute selector to account for spaces in the alt name. I also changed the overlay approach when you hover over the images. Check here: http://collaboratescience.com/so_34339/. click on download file to see the changes.

Comment: Alright I have everything set up nicely, however I wanted to add a pagination footer, however the numbers always show up to the left of my images. http://prntscr.com/i05l3k
The code im using, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpJKbw

Comment: This is now beyond the scope of the original question. You should mark answer as correct, and post your new questions separately.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I was searching the web for something like this to help my viewers find a image for a gallery of images.  This is better then what I could imagine and the code is easy to apply!  Absolutely wonderful.  I up voted this.