# How to set the image search box to 'None' or 'Off'?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the code prepared by @Cybernetic which can be found here ([Active Search Bar for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180339/active-search-bar-for-images)). The code is mainly for searching for images through a search box using jquery.  @Cybernetic did an outstanding job with his code and I couldn't post a comment there because I don't have enough points. I wish he can see this posting and answer my question.
What I wanted to ask about is whether we can set the code to hide images when we run it. Because I am using this code with hundreds of relatively large images! So, running it will load all these images at once which is causing the browser to slow down.
So, again, how can we set it to show no images until we start typing in the search box.
Thanks!

**Update**

```
<h2>Search for Image</h2>
<style>

.imgContainer{
    float:left;
}
img {
width: 1220px !important;
border: 3px; 
}
body {
background: white !important; 
}
.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.imgContainer:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
img{
border: 5px solid #33cc33;
}



</style>


<!-- <button type="mybutton">Click Me!</button> -->


<input type="text" id="myinput" name="search" placeholder="search..." style="width:600px; height: 40px; border-radius: 4px; font-size: 18px;"><br><br>
<center>
<div id="images">

<img src="C:\dir..............\image-1.jpg"  width=1130></a>
<img src="C:\dir..............\image-2.jpg"  width=1130></a>
<img src="C:\dir..............\image-3.jpg"  width=1130></a>
<img src="C:\dir..............\image-4.jpg"  width=1130></a>
<img src="C:\dir..............\image-5.jpg"  width=1130></a>





</div>


<script>
$("#myinput").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (val === "")
        $('img').show();
    else {
        $('img').hide();
        val = val.split(" ").join("\\ ");
        $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show();
    }
});
<!-- $("#mybutton").on('click', function() { -->
    <!-- var myinput = $('#mytextbox'); -->
    <!-- var val = $.trim(myinput.value); -->
    <!-- if (val === "") -->
        <!-- $('img').show(); -->
    <!-- else { -->
        <!-- $('img').hide(); -->
        <!-- $("img[alt*=" + val + "]").show(); -->
    <!-- } -->
<!-- }); -->
</script>
```

Comment: sure you can use a button and change event to be onclick instead of keyup, so it will search only if you used your button click =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CHANGES**:

- added regExp check for special chars.
- edited result's style.
- set images display to none to display only on search.
- added hover action to images.
- add span to show no result found if search didn't met any images.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mybutton").on('click', function() {
    var mysrchbox = $("#myinput").val();
    mysrchbox = mysrchbox.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    var val = $.trim(mysrchbox);
    if (val === "") {
      $('#none').show();
      $('img').hide();
    } else {
      val = val.split(" ").join("\\ ");
      if ( $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").attr('alt') === undefined ) {
        $('#none').show();
        $('img').hide();
      } else {
      $('#none').hide();
      $('img').hide();
        $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show();
        $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").css('display', 'inline-flex');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white !important;
}

#images {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#images img {
background: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#images img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Search for Image</h2>

<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Search!">
<input type="text" id="myinput" name="search" placeholder="search..." style="width:50; height: 20px; border-radius: 4px; font-size: 18px;"><br><br>

<div id="images"><span id="none" hidden="true">no result related for your search.</span>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/108-1082674_bitcoin-png-bitcoin-clipart-transparent-png.png" alt="eBitcoin" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://png.pngitem.com/pimgs/s/692-6924771_blockchain-cryptocurrency-wallet-ethereum-dogecoin-hd-png-download.png" alt="Ethereum" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ripple-Logo.png" alt="Ripple" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://i.redd.it/tsmzy49d4adz.jpg" alt="eBitcoin Cash" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://freepikpsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/cardano-logo-png-5-Transparent-Images.jpg" alt="eCardano" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DJkf7M4VYAAgt8V.png" alt="NEM" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://bitkee.com/icons/litecoin-logo.png" alt="LiteCoin" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://bittrust.s3.amazonaws.com/1486429998.png" alt="Stellar Lumens" width=130></a>
</div>
```

Comment: wa alaykum alsalam, show me ur full code,

Comment: @dani you can check now the sniipet in my reply, goodluck

Comment: Thanks burham, but the code you posted has some bugs. Since I am using hundreds of images, the script runs and starts to load the images and show them, then after a few seconds images will hide and that causes the browser to slow down, unfortunately!

Comment: @dani it's the main script u mentioned in your question bud, but ok i'll edit it to you to keep images hidden until u click search button but there is so many other typos in this script still so it's just an example to work on it dude, u need to improve it ;) anyway i'm going to fix the images show related part for you =)

Comment: @dani take alook now =) just done your script, fixed issues too =) goodluck

Comment: the problem still there!! When I try the script on 10 or a bit more images the script works just fine and no delay or no images shown unless I start search process. But when I load my all 450 images into the script the browser takes a few seconds (2-3sec) to load images/showing them then hides them later.  Anyways, thanks for your patience and help. I will keep it as is and move on. Just to clarify something here, I apologize for looking such lazy here, but I am not a programmer, I just come to stackoverflow to take advantage of some scripts here to make my office work easier.

Comment: it might not load if you copied the css style as long as i added style display: none to all images related to the search box =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227388/discussion-between-burham-b-soliman-and-dani).